# Is there a better way to rewrite this structure where I have to get a few bits from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, structure

Rewriting structures from c++ to c#. And I am looking for the optimal solution to make my code transparent. Currently, I have to pass bool arrays to get a value for e.g. 4 bits.

C++ code:

```cpp
uint16_t afc :4;
uint16_t prp :3;
uint16_t prs :3;
uint16_t q101 :3;
uint16_t ez1 :1;
uint16_t cw :1; 
uint16_t wa_kb :1;
```

My C# code:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum MainScr_Enum : ushort
{
    None = 0,
    afc_1 = 1 << 0,
    afc_2 = 1 << 1,
    afc_3 = 1 << 2,
    afc_4 = 1 << 3,
    prp_1 = 1 << 4,
    prp_2 = 1 << 5,
    prp_3 = 1 << 6,
    prs_1 = 1 << 7,
    prs_2 = 1 << 8,
    prs_3 = 1 << 9,
    q101_1 = 1 << 10,
    q101_2 = 1 << 11,
    q101_3 = 1 << 12,
    ez1 = 1 << 13,
    cw = 1 << 14,
    wa_kb = 1 << 15,
}
```

And I have to use this method to get value:

```cs
var val = GetValueFromFlags(new bool[] {MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_1), MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_2), MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_3), MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_4),})

public int GetValueFromFlags(bool[] list)
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        value += Convert.ToInt32(list[i]) << i;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I never need afc_1 e.t.c values separately.

**Edit (test program):**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Flags flags = new Flags();
        var array = new byte[] { 2, 1, 1, 1 };
        flags.FromArray(array);
        var test = (int)flags.MainScr_Enum;
        flags.MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_1);
    }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class Flags
{
    public ushort TickTimer; 
    public MainScr_Enum MainScr_Enum;      
    public void FromArray(byte[] val)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(val, 0, ptr, size);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, this);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
[Flags]
public enum MainScr_Enum : ushort
{
    None = 0,
    afc_1 = 1 << 0,
    afc_2 = 1 << 1,
    afc_3 = 1 << 2,
    afc_4 = 1 << 3,
    prp_1 = 1 << 4,
    prp_2 = 1 << 5,
    prp_3 = 1 << 6,
    prs_1 = 1 << 7,
    prs_2 = 1 << 8,
    prs_3 = 1 << 9,
    q101_1 = 1 << 10,
    q101_2 = 1 << 11,
    q101_3 = 1 << 12,
    ez1 = 1 << 13,
    cw = 1 << 14,
    wa_kb = 1 << 15,
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for. Do you want to improve readability? Performance? What is the context you are using this?

Comment: @JonasH I wish the code was cleaner. Now to get the value for 4 bits I have to create arrays and use the GetValueFromFlags () methods, which seems unreadable. I have many structures in my program and now I have to do so for each value. Additionally, I have to do it a second time if I want to get this value elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and declare these variables as members like this and use.

```
ushort afc = 4;
ushort prp = 3;
ushort prs = 3;
ushort q101 = 3;
ushort ez1 = 1;
ushort cw = 1;
ushort wa_kb = 1;
```

Comment: Am I to understand that if I create a structure in this way, then after rewriting the structure with Marshal from 4 bytes, I will rewrite the values into these ushorts?

Comment: It dont work. The structure increases in size

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine various values from a `Flags` enum, you can just OR the values together like so:

```
var val = MainScr_Enum.afc_1 | MainScr_Enum.afc_2 | MainScr_Enum.afc_3 | MainScr_Enum.afc_4;
```

No need for a separate array and whatnot.

In this case `val` will be of type `MainScr_Enum`. If you want it to be an `int` you can just cast:

```
int val = (int)(MainScr_Enum.afc_1 | MainScr_Enum.afc_2 | MainScr_Enum.afc_3 | MainScr_Enum.afc_4);
```

Comment: I make a mistake I cant take value from this flags like this: MainScr_Enum.afc_1 I have to do that: MainScr_Enum.HasFlag(MainScr_Enum.afc_1) and when I take value with this "|" I get bool and cant cast it on int.

Comment: Why do you have to use `HasFlag()`?

Comment: I added program where can you test it. There isnt MainScr_Enum.afc_1 properties. I can only cast (int)MainScr_Enum and get full flag value.

Comment: Ah, so you have an `int` which you want to turn into a collection of `MainScr_Enum` values, is that correct?

Comment: I create the structure from the byte array. And it seems to me that breaking the value into 4 bit and then extracting values using a method as presented above is not optimal. As is the case with: afc. And i looking for more optimal solution.